# Failed to create datagram socket (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm using flutter and utilising the RawDatagramSocket in dart in order to send a WOL packet. My code works fine in IOS but in the android emulator I keep getting this error

`Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed to create datagram socket (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13), address = 0.0.0.0, port = 9`

I have these permissions in my android manifest but I still can't get it to stop erroring:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Example of usage is shown below:

```
class WakeOnLanService {
  Future wake(InternetAddress ipAddress, MacAddress macAddress, int port) {
    return RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port)
        .then((RawDatagramSocket udpSocket) {
      udpSocket.broadcastEnabled = true;

      List<int> macBytes = macAddress.bytes;
      List<int> packet = new List<int>(17 * 6);
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) packet[i] = 0xFF;
      for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) packet[i * 6 + j] = macBytes[j];

      udpSocket.send(packet, ipAddress, port);
      udpSocket.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: are you running on emulator or physical device?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Emulator

Comment: You can't open UDP sockets with port numbers < 1024. Looks like you are trying to use port 9.

Comment: @RichardHeap is there any way for me to bind to port 9 then? It works completely as expected in iOS.

Comment: Not on Android.

Comment: Why do you need to send the UDP packet *from* port 9? Can you send it from an ephemeral port?

Comment: @RichardHeap I'm using it for wake on LAN and this usually uses UDP ports 0, 7 or 9. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet

Comment: Are you sending the wol packet from the flutter app or to the flutter app. You can do the former but not the latter.

Comment: @RichardHeap I'm sending a wol packet to my PC from the flutter app. On iOS it works perfectly and my computer wakes up but on android I just get the error saying failed to open Datagram socket.

Comment: You should be sending it from an ephemeral port even on iOS. You should be able to send from any port on your phone to port 9 on your PC.

Comment: @RichardHeap I've updated the question to include the code I'm using. I am now binding to port 49152 and attempting to send to port 9. The error is not happening anymore but my PC doesn't wake up from iOS or Android now.

Comment: It seems like to only be able to do this with iOS.

Comment: @RichardHeap damn that's annoying. It seems like this person has been able to new up an instance of DatagramSocket without any parameters in Java. I wish I could do that but I can't in dart! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273956/android-wake-on-lan-in-java

Comment: Interestingly, that java code doesn't bind to port 9 either. It seems to use an ephemeral port. It's simple to write a plugin to send the datagram packet. You could even prepare it in dart and just hand the 17*6 bytes across to native.

Comment: @RichardHeap could something like this work? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Yes there's even a video... https://www.meetup.com/flutter-nyc/events/258294868/

Comment: Did you try it on android device??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use ephemeral port (like in java, as mentioned in comments) just pass 0 to bind.

```
    return RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0)
```

It's not documented, here is an issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35147

Quote:

> If port has the value 0 an ephemeral port will be chosen by the system. The actual port used can be retrieved using the port getter.